# email sending with delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, email

I wrote my website with Ruby on Rails. I want to add mail services to my app so that at a specific state a user gets an email that contain some details for them. My problem is when I test in development mode I get emails at least with one hours delay and I don't know why? Does it depend on server configuration?

I use Amazon as my email gateway

This is my code for sending emails

```
 module Api
   module V1
     module User
      module DailyCheckin
       class Create


      attribute :state, ::String
      attribute :user, ::User

      validates :state, presence: true
      validates :user, presence: true

      def call

        add_error!(I18n.t('messages.daily_checkin.errors.state_invalid')) unless state.present?
        @checkin = ::DailyCheckin.create!(
            mood: ::Mood.find_by(state: state),
            user: user
        )
        if state == "overwhelmed" || state == "not_coping"
          logs = {
              user_id: user.id,
              email: user.profile.email,
              organisation: user.organisation.name,
              phone_number: user.profile.phone,
              mood: state
          }

          ::Api::V1::ApiGateway::Mail::DailyCheckinRiskNotice.call(logs: logs) if ENV.fetch("SEND_GATEWAY_MAIL", "true").eql? "true"
          DailyCheckinRiskWorker.perform_async(user.profile.email, user.profile&.current_first_name, "daily_checkin_risk")
        end
        add_error!(Helpers::ErrorsHandler.parse(@checkin.errors)) unless @checkin.valid?
        context[:mood] = @checkin.mood
      end
    end
  end
end
 end
 end
```

and this is my gatways

```
module Api
  module V1
    module ApiGateway
      module Mail
       class DailyCheckinRiskNotice
         include HTTParty
          attribute :logs

      validates :logs, presence: true

      def call
        options = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'x-api-key' => ENV.fetch('MAIL_API_GATEWAY_API_KEY', '')
            },
            body: {
                email_id: ENV.fetch('USER_ACTIVITY_NOTICE_MAIL_ID', ''),
                content: {
                    logs: logs
                }
            }.to_json
        }
        response = HTTParty.post('', options)
        add_error!(response.body) unless [201, 200].include?(response.code.to_i)

        context[:body] = response.parsed_response
      end
    end
    end
   end
  end
end
```

this is my mood model

```
class Mood < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: %i[not_coping overwhelmed ok good great]

  has_many :daily_checkins
 end
```

and this my create method that create my logs is state was not coping or overwelmed

```
 def create
    result = ::Api::V1::User::DailyCheckin::Create.call(create_checkin_params.merge(user: @current_user))
    return render json: Helpers::ErrorsHandler.view_parse(result.errors), status: :bad_request if result.errors

    @mood = result.mood
    render 'api/v1/moods/show'
  end
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using ActionMailer to send emails?

Comment: I would suggest not using SES directly on local. It's easier to test with something like Mailcatcher or Mailhog - cheaper too.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous is spot on. Test the actual live email provider in production or staging.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous No I'm just followed designing of projects that my boss want

Comment: @HadiVarposhti there could be several reasons for the delay. The code you posted has a lot of non-idiomatic patterns for a Rails project. Without further information, it's difficult to deduce why you are facing this delay.

That said, SMTP will make things easier to test. I suggest that you have a discussion with you boss about the reasoning behind this design.

Comment: @TheGeorgeous you right I've to talk to him , of course Now I check my description and add more details witch I think it's helpful